# How to have a default word in a vscode snippet (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm new in vscode and I'm adding a snippet for my python.
my snippet is this

```
"for i in a range": {
    "prefix": "for",
    "body": [
        "for i in range($1,$2):",
        "\t$3"
    ],
```

In the $3 I want to have a "pass" as default and when I tap "tab" for the third time I want to select the pass for me and I change it if I wanted to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a `placeholder`, see [snippet placeholders](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_placeholders).

So this code would work:

```
"for i in a range": {
    "prefix": "for",
    "body": [
        "for i in range($1,$2):",
        "\t${3:my default text}"
    ]
}
```

All of `my default text` will be seleced when you get to that tabstop, you can either overwrite it or tab again to complete the snippet.